# how to find out moved files from specific directory in linux in last 24 hour or 1 hour

Tags: linux, unix

I have to create a shell script to find out moved files from specific directory in linux in last 24 hour or last 1 hour .

Comment: This questions belongs in the [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stackoverflow.

Comment: yes it belong to unix/linux

Comment: Remove it from here and ask in the other forum please.